# maximum average gpa sql

Tags: sql, max, average

Alright so this is the question that I need to answer: Which department/major has the highest average GPA?

I am fairly new to SQL, actually I have only been doing it for 3 weeks now. I have the answer of the highest average GPA, but I want to know how to get it to display the major and the gpa, not just the gpa.

```
    select max (avg_gpa)
    from (select major, avg(gpa) AS avg_gpa
    from lab5_student
    group by major);
```

Thank you for any insight into this!

Pat

Answer (score 1):

Add the major column to the select statement like below:

```
  select major, max (avg_gpa)
    from (select major, avg(gpa) AS avg_gpa
    from lab5_student
    group by major);
```

This should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select y.* from
(
 SELECT MAX(avg_gpa) as max_avg_gpa
 FROM (
       SELECT major,AVG(gpa) AS avg_gpa
       FROM lab5_student
       GROUP BY major
      )v
 )x
 inner join

(
       SELECT major,AVG(gpa) AS avg_gpa
       FROM lab5_student
       GROUP BY major
)y
on x.max_avg_gpa=y.avg_gpa
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43d89/21)**